# identify change of values in vector

Tags: r

I once used a very handy `r` function that could return a vector whose value were incremented at each change in another variable. 
Here would be my input `data.frame`, generated with the following code:

`set.seed(0)
data.frame(Day=seq(as.Date("2016-10-01"),as.Date("2016-10-10"),by="day"),
           bit=sample(c(0,1),size=10,replace=TRUE))`

```
Day          bit
2016-10-01   1
2016-10-02   0
2016-10-03   0
2016-10-04   1
2016-10-05   1
2016-10-06   0
2016-10-07   1
2016-10-08   1
2016-10-09   1
2016-10-10   1
```

I would need the extra column `bit.change`

```
Day          bit bit.change
2016-10-01   1   1
2016-10-02   0   2
2016-10-03   0   2
2016-10-04   1   3
2016-10-05   1   3
2016-10-06   0   4
2016-10-07   1   5
2016-10-08   1   5
2016-10-09   1   5
2016-10-10   1   5
```

I have a solution comparing `bit` with its lagged value but it is not elegant.
Does anybody know what function i mean?
If possible, it should work with `dplyr::mutate()` and `dplyr::group_by()`.  If `group_by()` is specified the `bit.change` should start again from `1` at each new group.
Thx a lot for your help!

Comment: See `rleid()` in `data.table` for one such implementation of this. I'm sure this is a duplicate question but `cumsum(abs(c(1,diff(df$bit))))` will also do it in base R.

Comment: Thx. `rleid()` was what I was looking for. Thx also for the alternative suggestion with `cumsum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df %>%
  mutate(bit.change=cumsum(c(1, diff(bit) != 0)))

          Day bit bit.change
1  2016-10-01   1          1
2  2016-10-02   0          2
3  2016-10-03   0          2
4  2016-10-04   1          3
5  2016-10-05   1          3
6  2016-10-06   0          4
7  2016-10-07   1          5
8  2016-10-08   1          5
9  2016-10-09   1          5
10 2016-10-10   1          5
```